# PHP include by name

Tags: php, include, directory

I have a `content` folder which is full of other sub-directories named in the following way:

```
id1_1
id1_2
id1_3
id2_1
id2_2
```

And so on. Each of these folders contains a file `template.php`.

The number of folders is dynamic, so I need to find a way to import all the `template.php` from all folders starting with `id_1_` into my `index.php` file. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the glob() function:

```
$arrFiles = glob('./id_1_*/template.php');
foreach($arrFiles as $file) {
     include_once($file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function + foreach + glob:

http://www.php.net/glob

Comment: Just to add: recursion will only needed if you need to descend into infinite depth (i.e. sub-sub-sub folders), but by the sounds of it, you might not need it.